# Which console versions of Diablo 3 ROS have Kanai's Cube?

Tags: diablo-iii, version-differences, diablo-iii-console

I don't seem to be able to dig this answer up on the internet. I'm wondering which (if any) console versions of Diablo 3, Reaper of Souls, have Kanai's cube. AFAIK, it doesn't exist on our ancient Xbox360 version. If we upgrade to the Xbox X (and presumably run the Xbox One version in backward compat?) will we have access to Kanai's?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/d3/t/kanai-cube-on-xbox-360/11065):

> It is not possible to acquire it. This is due to the fact that 360 and PS3 versions are limited to version 2.0.6 of the game. The Cube was added in patch 2.3 and other platforms are already on patch 2.6.7.

So any version lower than 2.3 won't have Kanai's Cube.

Comment: Looks like I'll need to buy a new xbox one edition as well to run on the newer machine. Good to know. Thanks for digging that up.